# Loading more than one buttons in the same location or not

Tags: c#, xna

I am writing a UI interface with user input and buttons. I need to ask the user to input some number and then press the button labelled "solve", which needs to determine whether the number is correct. I try to use only one button to solve it in the beginning. Here is my code:

```
if (correct)
{
    solveButton = new MenuButton(contentManager.Load<Texture2D>("solve"), 
        buttonCenter, GameState.AnswerNo);
}
else
{
    solveButton = new MenuButton(contentManager.Load<Texture2D>("solve"),
        buttonCenter, GameState.AnswerYes);
}
```

When loading it, under the draw method, I use the following code:

```
solveButton.Draw(spriteBatch);
```

Here, `GameState.AnswerNo` and `GameState.AnswerYes` lead to different pages standing for the correct and incorrect answers, respectively. However, it doesn't work as I thought it would - it always goes to `GameState.AnswerNo` page no matter the "correct" value is.

Therefore, I am thinking about using two buttons (button figures are the same but move position a little):

```
solveButton = new MenuButton(contentManager.Load<Texture2D>("solve"),
    buttonCenter, GameState.AnswerNo);

buttonCenter.Y -= 40;

solveButton2 = new MenuButton(contentManager.Load<Texture2D>("solve"),
    buttonCenter, GameState.AnswerYes);
```

And when loading them:

```
if (correct)
{
    solveButton.Draw(spriteBatch);
}

if (!correct)
{
    solveButton2.Draw(spriteBatch);
}
```

Which works fine, but the awkward thing is that when the user inputs the correct number, `button1` will disappear and `button2` will appear just under it. Any better ideas to complete this function?

Comment: Why not give both buttons the same location?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Using both button at the same location only return me one answer no matter the input.

Comment: This sounds like you may be looking at the wrong part of your code. It sounds like your solveButton is not being reassigned/redrawn correctly, but it's hard to know for sure with the code given.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking at the problem wrong.

Instead of using two different buttons, why are you not just using one button, and then set the state via a function?

1. User inputs value, and presses button.
2. Button calls function, checks if value is correct.
3. Based on result, set the active state.